# How to get the post of selected subcategory only

Tags: wordpress

I have three drop-down select option. Inside each drop-down, I have shown the Sub-category for example shown below.

Service

- Mobile development
- Web development
- Software development

Technology

- Android
- IOS
- Java

Industry

- Commerce
- Education
- Lifestyle

Here Service, Technology, and Industry are the category of CPT and inside it like Mobile Development, IOS and Commerce are the sub-categories of the main category.

Now what I want to do on change of any of the three category show post of that sub-category only.

For example, if I select IOS then show the post of IOS only similar with others if the user selects IOS, Mobile Development, and Lifestyle then show post of all three.

To achieve this I have to use the change jQuery function and calling the ajax on change event. The problem is I am getting the same post for all the post select please help me through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$posts_array = get_posts(
array(
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'post_type' => 'acme_portfolio',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_category',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => array($post_id),
        )
    )
));
```

Put this in function.php

Answer (score 0):

You Can achieve this by Following this -

Firstly You Register a Custom Post Type like 'Course' in my Code.
Then you need to Add Custom Taxonomy For this like 'Course Type' in my Code.

Then get All Posts with using Page Template or Any other method which you are followed.
I add this code in my Page Template then attach those Page Template to a Page, Here i get all posts when page reload with thre Select boxes for Parent Terms like 'Service', 'Technology', 'Industry' -

```
    <div class="course_content">
        <?php $parent_terms = get_terms( 'course_type', array( 'parent' => 0 ) );
        foreach( $parent_terms as $parent_term ){

            $children_terms = get_terms('course_type', array('parent' => $parent_term->term_id) );

            if($children_terms){
                ?>
                    <select class="select_course_type <?php echo 'course_type-'.$parent_term->slug; ?>">
                        <option value=""><?php echo 'Select '.$parent_term->name; ?></option>
                        <?php
                            foreach( $children_terms as $children_term ){
                                echo '<option value="'.$children_term->slug.'">'.$children_term->name.'</option>';
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="selected_course_type" />
        <div class="display_posts">
            <?php 
                $args = array( 
                'post_type' => 'course',
                );

                $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
            ?>
            <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
                echo '<ul>';
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

                <li>
                    <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title() ;?></a></h4>
                </li>
                <?php endwhile; 
                    echo '</ul>';
                endif;

                wp_reset_query(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then you add jquery code in your JS File For Calling Ajax, like this -

```
$('.select_course_type').on('change', function(){
        var s = $(this).val();

        $("option", this).removeAttr('selected');
        $("option[value='" + s + "']", this).attr('selected', 'selected');

        ct_Array = [];
        $('.select_course_type').each(function(){
            var t = $(this).val();
            if(t != ''){
                ct_Array.push($(this).val()); 
            } 
        });

        var ajax_url = FrontAjax.ajaxurl;

        data = {
            action: 'ajax_filter_for_courses',
            s_ctValues: ct_Array,
        };

        $.post( ajax_url, data, function(response) {
            if( response ){
                $('.display_posts').html(response);
            }
        });
});
```

Then add this code in Functions.php File for getting Posts after Filter-

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_filter_for_courses', 'filter_for_courses');
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_filter_for_courses', 'filter_for_courses');
function filter_for_courses() {

   $explode_ct = $_POST['s_ctValues'];  
   $tax_query = array();

   if(isset($explode_ct)) {
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'course_type',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $explode_ct
        );
    }

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'course',
        'tax_query' => $tax_query
    );
    $filter_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $filter_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<ul>';
        while ( $filter_query->have_posts() ) : $filter_query->the_post();
            ?>
            <li>
                <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title() ;?></a></h4>
            </li>
            <?php
        endwhile;
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    wp_reset_query();

    die(); //stop "0" from being output
}
```

Comment: Thanks IncipientInfo I will try this and let you know.

Comment: Hello IncipientInfo I have used the code you have provided. But on change it show all the post from that CPT. What I want for example if I select Mobile Development which is subcategory from its parent category called Service so it should show the Post which select under the Mobile development only so basically what I need I have applied the ajax and front end code that show three box inside that we have sub-category . I need code in function.php which call by the ajax on change on select of particular post show post of that subcategory only.Please help me for that and thanks for your help.

Comment: Hello Sandy, 
When you change the Select box to Mobile Application Subcategory then you can get Posts related to those subcategory only with Ajax.
I already provide ajax function code here, you can add those code in functions.php file for ajax call.

Comment: Hello IncipientInfo  thanks for reply I have applied the given code also but it show all the post of that Post type not showing particular post. As I have mention before also I want when user click to subcategory of Service (Here Service is parent category) i.e Mobile development so it should show the post selected for subcategory mobile development only. the given code is fetch all the post please help me I am stuck here.
Thanks Again!

Comment: 'taxonomy' => 'course_type', here my taxonomy is "portfolio_category" register_taxonomy('portfolio_category', array( 'acme_portfolio' ), $args ); I write this code in the function.php to create cpt and taxonomy but getting all post not particular post  please let me know where I am going wrong.
Thanks!

Comment: I think you don't replace Taxonomy Slug each and every place so please change the taxonomy & Post Type Slug in my Code then apply it.
Or i think your Ajax response is not Display so will you please check you div class For displaying Ajax response like in my code i add a class display_posts in Html structure then print the Response there like this: $('.display_posts').html(response);

So please check this i hope it will resolve your Issue.

Comment: I have replace all of them and yes my ajax is also working properly and I have replace all the taxonomy and post type. their is no any problem with the ajax response and other things such as the post type and taxonomy also I have replace I am getting the response also but not what I need using your code it fetch all the post not post of selected Sub-category only. I need your help to get the post of the sub-category selected only for this.

Thanks!

Comment: Also when I alert  var t = $(this).val(); this value i.e alert( t ); it show blank i.e is not showing any value I am using all the classes correctly on change function working but not getting any thing here.

Comment: I found the solution my self by thank you so much IncipientInfo you help me lot and your advice is very help full.